# Driving 36V LED from 12V Supply

Tags: power-supply, led, dc-dc-converter, constant-current

I have a chip-on-board LED that requires 36V max, 300 mA, but I have a power supply designed for a <s>12V max, 900 mA LED</s>.  The power supply is a pretty standard constant current power supply that outputs 900 mA for the LED and adjusts the voltage as required.

Is there a simple way to take this output and convert it from 900 mA to 300 mA without disrupting the constant current power supply's regulation?  I am aware things like buck converters exist but I am unsure if they will function properly in this instance.

[Link to the LED in question](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T72NVRQ)

The power supply is part of a larger unit and cannot be replaced.  Solutions that only supply partial power to the LED (at least 5W) would be acceptable.

**Update**: I dug the old power supply out of the unit and discovered it is capable of 16V max at 16W max.  It supplies 1A at 10.06V to a LED currently.

[Link to the power supply currently used (Model: RLDD015L-1000)](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1448856.pdf)

Comment: Definitely not without abandoning the existing regulation.  There are of course step-up drivers for higher voltage LEDs but those either do the regulation or need it to be re-created.  There might be a way to "game" the existing driver into a power supply, but you'd probably be better off starting with an ordinary voltage mode supply (vs LED driver) or really just buying a power supply/driver directly compatible with your LEDs.

Comment: You won't get 36 volts at 300 mA from a 12 volts (max) limiting current at 900 mA (due to power conversion efficiency being about 90%)

Comment: What kind of LED board requires "36V max"? That's suspicious - can you provide a link or schematic?

Comment: You'll probably want to switch to a boost regulator with it's own current regulation.

Comment: Added the LED to the question.  We would really want to run the LED from this supply, Losing some power would be acceptable here.  Dropping to 250 mA after conversion would be acceptable for example.

Comment: It's 38 volt max hence there are no guarantees especially as there is no data sheet I can find.

Comment: There would be real value in gaming the existing driver since it is part of a larger setup (There is automation involved in turning it on and off etc).  An answer that gives a solution with power losses and isn't ideal would be perfectly fine.

Comment: It specifies a 34-38V range and 10 Watts. Your 12V/900mA supply is 11W but you won't get 10W at 38V after conversion and even if you could that's much too stressful for the supply. It's probable you could run at lower wattage and it just won't be as bright. But if you want the full 10W you will definitely need a different supply, at which point you'd do yourself a big favor by getting one with the suggested voltage in the first place.

Comment: I agree that changing the power supply is better, but say I accepted a lower limit of 5 watts for the final LED.  Are there any solutions to this problem that don't involving changing that?

Comment: @Tristan Maxson There is always a solution for everything. But they will be all far more complicated, inefficient and expensive than just adding a AC-DC 300mA +-36V constant current supply connected to the main power line.

Comment: How does the existing driver work? Does it use PWM? So the average output current is 900mA * duty cycle? What is the switching frequency?

Comment: added some additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solutions that only supply partial power to the LED (at least 5W) would be acceptable.

It may not be possible with what you have at hand.

Most 36V-COBs start to illuminate at 25-28V. For yours, it could be around 28V/10mA *(I'm just guessing as there's no datasheet available.)*. So there's no chance to drive that LED with your LED driver as the max allowed output voltage is 12V.

Even if the LED driver is part of another system and cannot be replaced, you may have an option to use a separate, appropriate LED driver only for that LED. Or, if it's not vital to use that LED, maybe you should consider using a different one that your LED driver "likes".

But remember that,

- You can't use your existing LED driver,

- You can't convert 0.9A constant current (12V max) to 0.3A constant current (36+V max). <sup>If someone knows a CC-to-CC converter, please let me know.</sup>

Comment: OK, I retracted my simplistic answer of just generating 36V. You're right - these constant current devices are different animals. Thanks!

Comment: I actually know experimentally that it pulls about 15 mA at 29V, so you are very spot on.  a CC-to-CC converter seems like what I would want but like you mention I have never seen one even as just a circuit.